# I want to deleted an image from Cloudinary, but not working this code

Tags: php, cloudinary

I want to delete an existing image from Cloudinary. I have fetched public id of that image but not working delete code.

```
\Cloudinary::config(array(
  "cloud_name" => $cloud_name,//"demo", 
  "api_key" => $api_key,//"286877943699458", 
  "api_secret" => $api_secret//"gNr8jY6sCYyihv8mrcoJHq4AaAw" 
));


$image1 = $image1_arr->public_id; //public id is present in image1_arr array
\Cloudinary\Uploader::destroy($image1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary's default `type` is `upload`. If you want to delete a fetched image, add the `type` to the destroy call -

`\Cloudinary\Uploader::destroy($image1,array("type" => "fetch"));`

If it's not the case, share the full error message for more details.